# Invariant Violation: When using graphql Mutation on nextjs 13

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, next.js13

all my query is working well, except for my graphql mutation. hope you can help.

I'm using the same code on my other project, the only difference is this form is inside a modal.

[error on showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QfBk.png)

And I know this mutation on my playground is working

[graphql playground working mutation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N17kO.png)

here's my full registration file

```
"use client";
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { gql, useMutation } from "@apollo/client";
import { useForm, SubmitHandler } from "react-hook-form";
import Modal from "../Modal/Modal";
import { ModalContext } from "@/app/contex/modal";

// Define the GraphQL mutation
const REGISTER_USER_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation RegisterUser($input: RegisterInput!) {
    register(input: $input) {
      jwt
      user {
        id
        username
        email
        confirmed
        role {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

interface RegistrationFormData {
  username: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

const Register: React.FC = () => {
  const modalContext = useContext(ModalContext);

  // Ensure that modalContext is not undefined before using its properties
  if (!modalContext) {
    throw new Error("ModalContext not available");
  }

  const { modalStatus, setModalStatus } = modalContext;
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    formState: { errors },
    watch,
  } = useForm<RegistrationFormData>();

  // Define the useMutation hook with types
  const [registerUser, { loading, error, data }] = useMutation<{
    register: { jwt: string; user: User };
  }>(REGISTER_USER_MUTATION);

  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<RegistrationFormData> = async (data) => {
    try {
      const response = await registerUser({
        variables: {
          input: {
            username: data.username,
            email: data.email,
            password: data.password,
          },
        },
      });

      if (response.errors) {
        // Handle GraphQL errors here, e.g., display error messages
        console.error("GraphQL errors:", response.errors);
        return;
      }

      // Handle successful registration
      console.log("User registration response:", response.data);

      // Reset the form after successful registration
      reset();
    } catch (err) {
      // Handle registration error, e.g., display an error message
      console.error("Registration error:", err);
    }
  };

  const password = watch("password");

  return (
    <Modal>
      <h1>Register</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        {/* Form fields and validation errors remain the same */}
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="username"
            {...register("username", { required: "Username is required" })}
          />
          {errors.username && <span>{errors.username.message}</span>}
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            id="email"
            {...register("email", { required: "Email is required" })}
          />
          {errors.email && <span>{errors.email.message}</span>}
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            id="password"
            {...register("password", { required: "Password is required" })}
          />
          {errors.password && <span>{errors.password.message}</span>}
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            id="confirmPassword"
            {...register("confirmPassword", {
              required: "Please confirm your password",
              validate: (value) =>
                value === password || "Passwords do not match",
            })}
          />
          {errors.confirmPassword && (
            <span>{errors.confirmPassword.message}</span>
          )}
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit">Register</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setModalStatus(""); // Clear modal status
        }}
      >
        Close
      </button>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default Register;
```

"lib/apollo-wrapper.js"

```
"use client";

import {
  ApolloClient,
  ApolloLink,
  HttpLink,
} from "@apollo/client";
import {
  ApolloNextAppProvider,
  NextSSRInMemoryCache,
  SSRMultipartLink, 
  NextSSRApolloClient
} from "@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/ssr";

function makeClient() {
  const httpLink = new HttpLink({
      // https://studio.apollographql.com/public/spacex-l4uc6p/
      uri: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_ENDPOINT,
  });

  return new NextSSRApolloClient({
    cache: new NextSSRInMemoryCache(),
    link:
      typeof window === "undefined"
        ? ApolloLink.from([
            new SSRMultipartLink({
              stripDefer: true,
            }),
            httpLink,
          ])
        : httpLink,
  });
}

export function ApolloWrapper({ children }) {
  return (
    <ApolloNextAppProvider makeClient={makeClient}>
      {children}
    </ApolloNextAppProvider>
  );
}
```

"lib/client.js"

```
import { ApolloClient, HttpLink, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";
import {
  NextSSRInMemoryCache,
  NextSSRApolloClient,
} from "@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/ssr";
import { registerApolloClient } from "@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/rsc";

export const { getClient } = registerApolloClient(() => {
  return new NextSSRApolloClient({
    cache: new NextSSRInMemoryCache(),
    link: new HttpLink({
      // https://studio.apollographql.com/public/spacex-l4uc6p/
      uri: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_ENDPOINT,
      // you can disable result caching here if you want to
      // (this does not work if you are rendering your page with `export const dynamic = "force-static"`)
      // fetchOptions: { cache: "no-store" },
    }),
  });
});
```

To resolve the bug, and continue with the form submission

Answer (score 1):

Solved

I dont have to pass the object in the variables {}

Instead of

```
const response = await registerUser({
        variables: {
          input: {
            username: data.username,
            email: data.email,
            password: data.password,
          },
        },
      });
```

It should be

```
const response = await registerUser({
        variables: {
          username: data.username,
          email: data.email,
          password: data.password,
        },
      });
```

Mutation

```
export const CREATE_USER_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation register(
    $username: String!,
    $password: String!,
    $email: String!,
  ) {
    register(
      input: {
        username: $username,
        password: $password,
        email: $email,
      }
    ) {
      jwt
      user {
        id
        username
        email
        confirmed
        role {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

and "use client"; on top of the js file

The default error message is not informative enough.
so I added this on top

```
import { loadErrorMessages, loadDevMessages } from "@apollo/client/dev";

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
  loadErrorMessages();
  loadDevMessages();
}
```